# Can one rotate the chanukiyah after lighting it?

Tags: halacha, menora-chanukia, pirsumei-nissa

Some *chanukiyot* have back-plates, like this one:

[image: photo]

When lighting such a *chanukiyah* in a window, it seems preferable to have the lights facing the street to maximize the publicity.  (For the one in the photo, the lights are visible over the back-plate for some minutes, but not enough to meet the *halachic* requirement.)  But lighting with it in that position can be tricky.  Is one permitted to rotate the *chanukiyah* after lighting?  I know we can't move it from inside to outside after lighting ([Shabbat 22b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.22b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [OC 675.1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.675.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and must "light it in its place"; I don't know whether that means no movement at all or just no relocation.

(This is not a *l'ma'aseh* question despite that being my photo; with multiple *chanukiyot* one can publicize in both directions.  I'm just wondering if one who had to choose would be able to rotate this kind of *chanukiyah*.)

Comment: Hello, Monica, thank you so much for posting your comment at Meta.SE saying that you are participating at Mi Yodeya.  I am so happy to see signs of normal life.  What a nice New Year's present.

Answer (score 6):

The Rivevos Ephraim 5:428 addresses this . He brings Mishna Berurah 671:30 which notes that if one lights in a place that is less than 20 amos and then moves it to another place which is also lower than 20 amos one is yotzeh,since both places is kosher. He also brings the Shaar Hatzion 34 brings the Machtzis Hashekel and says this is pashut(obvious). However ,in siman 675:6 writes that one should be careful not to move it until the shiur of half hour has passed since some are machmir.

Text of Rivevos Ephraim:

On a side note: The Midwest Agudah of Illinois put out a Chanuka guide which details what to do when one has such a menorah. It should be noted that Rav Shmeul Feurst reviewed all halachos before it was published.

[image][image]

Comment: I don't understand the proof you bring. Once you light it less than 20 the mitzva is done. One can't become not yotzei even if they go out. The Gemaras case was bringing outside after lighting when you weren't yotzei yet; lighting outside and bringing inside is no worse than כבתה. The only question is was it lechatchila to move it and does the candle still have a chalot mitzva (NM for Birkat haRoeh and Issur Hanaa).

Comment: I’m stunned that the Machtzis Hashekel says this is obvious. I assume Shaar Hatzion is on 671 as well? Does he quote where in the Machtzis Hashekel?

Comment: @doubleaa its not me but the Rivevos and MB,I will post the actual text shortly

Comment: @DonielF ,I'm sry I edited the text,its the CC who says and its pashut ,not the MH

Comment: @Doniel the MHsh references OC 263:10, see MA there. It seems hed only allow it not immediately after lighting it. See too Darkei Moshe and Pri Chadash to 675